# External CSS in React Typescript NPM package

Tags: typescript, rollupjs, npm-publish

I have a React Typescript Storybook project that I have used to create some components. I am using Rollup to bundle these components up (the non-storybook files) up as a reusable NPM package.

I have this working apart from the fact that my components use bootstrap for the styling - how do I /what is the best way to bundle this into my package?

Answer (score 0):

I got round this by using require JS. For example in my index.ts file i do the following:

```
import logo from "./stories/assets/scts-logo-sm.png";
require("bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");
require("bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css");

export { logo };
export * from "./stories/Button";
export * from "./stories/Footer";
export * from "./stories/Header";
```

Don't know if this is best practice - the storybook/rollup documentation isn't very good on this.... CSS Modules might be another way to do it